# Do not show folders in "This PC" but in User folder

Tags: windows-10

Following [this](https://www.askvg.com/tip-remove-6-extra-folders-from-windows-10-explorer-this-pc/) guide, I managed to remove undesired folders section from "This PC".

Unfortunately I now found out that they also disappeared from the *special* user folder.

I mean, if I open `C:\Users\<username>\` they are still there, but when I open the *special* user folder (for example from the icon on desktop) they doesn't appear.

Is there any way to have them in the user folder, other then reverting the ThisPCPolicy entry in register (and have them back in "This PC", which I don't want)?

Comment: From which icon on desktop did you open? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: The "User's file" icon you can enable from here http://www.isunshare.com/images/article/windows-10/remove-desktop-icons-on-windows-10/deselect-desktop-icons-and-tap-ok.png